JAX-WS Dispatch API hangs forever on HttpTimeoutException
We are using JAX-WS Dispatch API to call a SOAP service.
We faced a critical issue when a target SOAP service went down, because the JAX-WS client was hanging (about 6 hours) and when the service was restored the client sent an invalid call (the transaction should have been cancelled after a timeout period).
Seems the JAX-WS Dispatch API loops forever until the WSDL is available. Is this a bug? Or there is a feature/configuration to fail the call invocation when a predefined timeout is reached?
I created a sample project to demonstrate this behavior:
https://github.com/jbaris/cxf-connection-issue
Thanks in advance!
